# UIScrollview delegate methods aren't being called for UICollectionview

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionview which I populate with custom cells horizontally. But I'd like to do scrollViewDidScroll things but non of the UIScrollView delegate methods are being called. Am I missing something?

EDIT:
Ok I realized that the indexPath returns zero and breaks out. New question is why can't I get the correct value?

```
 func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    var visibleRect = CGRect()

    visibleRect.origin = containerView.contentOffset
    visibleRect.size = newView.frame.size


    let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
    let visibleIndexPath: IndexPath? = containerView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)


    guard let indexPath = visibleIndexPath else { return }
}
```

EDIT: The problem was newView.frame.size returns 0 I used the size of containerView and instead of scrollViewWillEndDragging I switched to scrollViewDidEndDecelerating.

Comment: Have you assigned the collection view delegate `collectionView.delegate = self`

Comment: Yes I did. I can't even print a simple message

Comment: can u post the code of scrollViewDidScroll

Comment: Is the view controller UICollectionViewDelegate or UIScrollViewDelegate

Comment: Updated the question